# java.net.unknownhostexception host is unresolved graph.facebook.com

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api

I have created app , that I am integrating with facebook. I followed all the steps for integrating with facebook. When I click on link to facebook in my app , it redirect to login screen of facebook, after giving the credentials , it is throwing the exception

```
java.net.unknownhostexception host is unresolved graph.facebook.com
```

I am able to open the facebook link.

Can anyone help on this

Comment: post some useful code after debugging

Comment: is this an android app?

Comment: No its java app only.

Comment: what does `cmd` say for `ping graph.facebook.com` ?

Comment: Try adding `https://` or `http://` before the address?